# Set Config Tab and Pinned Tabs(website) culture same as Team in a Teams App Package (C# and Blazor)

Tags: c#, blazor, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit, razor-components

I have a Teams app package which is built on C# and Blazor created using Microsoft Teams App project template. This website has pages for config tab and after selecting the item in config tab, there are pages which gets pinned in a channel. I used ASP.net code globalization and localization, which works well with Browser language. But instead of browser language, I would like to set the culture same as Teams(Current User Language in Teams). Did anyone worked on this scenario and point me to the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the code of setting culture and tab from OnAfterRenderAsync and addded in my event. It worked.

```
private async void SetSelectedResult(SearchModel selectedItem)
    {
        SetCulture();
        _selectedItem = selectedItem;
        if (_selectedItem != null)
        {
            var settings = new TeamsInstanceSettings
            {
                SuggestedDisplayName = _selectedItem.Description,
                EntityId = _selectedItem.ID.ToString(),
                ContentUrl = $"{NavigationManager.BaseUri}entity/{_selectedItem.ID}/{_selectedItem.EntityType}/{_selectedItem.Division}",
                WebsiteUrl = $"{NavigationManager.BaseUri}entity/{_selectedItem.ID}/{_selectedItem.EntityType}/{_selectedItem.Division}"
            };

            await MicrosoftTeams.InitializeAsync();
            await MicrosoftTeams.RegisterOnSaveHandlerAsync(settings);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your tab you have access to the Teams context object. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context) for more info on this. On the context object is a `locale`. That might be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: In addition to this being available in your tab via `getContext` API, you can also use a `{locale}` placeholder in URLs in your manifest, and they will get replaced with the local information before being launched in Teams. This way your service can have access to these as well and use them when generating the content returned to the client.

Comment: If I change the menifest file to this, will it be sufficient:                   
    `  "configurableTabs": [
    {
      "configurationUrl": "https://localhost:44357/config?local={locale}",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "scopes": [
        "team",
        "groupchat"
      ],
      "context": [
        "channelTab",
        "privateChatTab",
        "meetingChatTab",
        "meetingDetailsTab",
        "meetingSidePanel",
        "meetingStage"
      ]
    }
  ],`

Comment: It did not worked. My culture still falls back to browser language. However I can see t=in Iframe that correct culture is set. I am posting the screenshot in my question as I am not able to post here. The change of culture happens when I select the item or any event like after search hit enter.

Comment: @user25879 Can you please add the code snippet that is used to retrieve the culture ?

also this [blogpost](https://chrissainty.com/working-with-query-strings-in-blazor/) may have relevant patterns

Comment: In the Config tab, I am not using any code to get the culture but in manifest file, I updated the config url to have the locale like this : "configurationUrl": "localhost:44357/config?local={locale}",. So when in Teams Channel I click on add icon, I get the config tab and I get the correct culture in Iframe (Thats all dynamic  thanks to Local parameter), but as soon as I hit any event(click or select), my language falls back to browser language.

Comment: When you detect the locale this way, it will use the locale of the CURRENT user - whoever is ADDING the tab at the time using the config page. That means it will then be set to use the same locale for every single user. Is that what you're wanting, or are you wanting it to switch to using the locale of the logged in user, which could change user by user as they visit the tab?

Comment: I am able to reproduce the error in a new project : https://github.com/LALITAMITTAL18/TeamsApp-WebCulture.  The config tab language is always set to browser language not as per the Team. Though as I said because of the manifest file change IFrame shows the correct culture of Teams but still the web app is switched to browser language.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow yes indeed that's what I want.  I dont want any hardcoded culture but this should always change based on the Current user culture who is logged in Teams at that moment.

Comment: In that case, don't set it in the manifest file, and don't set it in the url for the content tab either - in both those cases it will be permanently fixed. The best option is use what I presented in the original answer - get the Teams context and get the locale from there. Getting Teams context is useful for other things too, like detecting if the user changes the theme while they're currently viewing your tab - you can respond to the change as well.

Comment: in C# solution, TeamsJsBlazorInterop.js is used to communicate with MS teams. There is a JSInterop class to use it. As it is JS, in Razor component you can only call it in OnAfterRenderAsync, nowhere else. So till the time I get the locale from the Teams context, I have only option left which is to set the culture like this:                         Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);
And this always fallback to default culture(Browser Language) on every Event call.

Comment: ah ok - that can be - I don't use Blazor so can't advise on that. Perhaps ask it as a more general Blazor question - what to do if you're waiting for a javascript component to load, and to receive a callback from it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245478/discussion-between-user25879-and-hilton-giesenow).